# How do I batch-assign NoData values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, masking, arccatalog, nodata

I have a number of rasters I need to mosaic together. The areas with data are within a rectangular "nan" envelope. The "nan" envelopes of different rasters overlap each other. No matter what mosaic operator I use in Mosaic to New Raster, areas are still overwritten with NoData.

Currently I can work around this by going into ArcCatalog, opening the properties for each raster, computing the NoData value in the NoData Editor, and applying it. Then when I mosaic the rasters they come out properly. But this is a tedious process when I'm dealing with dozens of rasters.

In ArcGis Pro, I can manually edit the NoData value of a raster in the source tab, but it cannot compute NoData values like ArcCatalog and I see nothing in the toolbox that allows me to automate this process.

How can I quickly compute and apply NoData values to many rasters?